# Maven dependency copy with Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

Here is a simple maven command:

```
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=com.mypackage:services-web:2.1-SNAPSHOT:war -DoutputDirectory=. -Dmdep.useBaseVersion=false
```

When I run it on machine where jenkins is installed from command line I get artifact:

```
services-web-2.1-20180116.225702-1.war
```

Which is what I want. However, running the same command with Jenkins (I tried both "Execute Windows batch" and "Invoke top-level Maven") I always get it this way:

```
services-web-2.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

With no timestamp. I would want to have timestamp and I cannot find any explanation why it strips it with Jenkins running it.

Comment: Your Jenkins may have a local repository in which a locally build version lies. This may have been drawn instead of your expected version.

Comment: JF Meier OMG thank you! I felt there could be something about Jenkins profile (I change the default maven installation to external one), but after your comment I got the idea to specify local repository which totally solved my problem. Thank you again.

Comment: Also I did check local repository of system profile /.m2 before (Jenkins runs as windows service, so his userhome resolves to systemprofile), but ,surprisingly, it shown to be empty (I have admin rights on it, afaik) - still not sure how it worked.